# How to setup a scrollview with many buttons in it?

Tags: ios, scrollview

I have been trying to add buttons on scroll view, but unable to do them. I want to add more 7 buttons in a view, but I want that user can get access to all seven buttons by scrolling down. How can I do that?

Please someone guide me or else provide me a link where I can understand.

EDIT:

I have created a view based application and named as poo1 & in the poo1ViewController.h,

```
@interface poo1ViewController  : UIViewController <infodelegate>
{
 IBOutlet UIButton *a;
 IBOutlet UIButton *b;
 IBOutlet UIButton *c;
 IBOutlet UIButton *d;
 IBOutlet UIButton *e;
 IBOutlet UIScrollView *fView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIScrollView *fView;;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *a;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *b;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *c;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *d;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *e;
-(IBAction) ia:(id)sender;
```

And in implementation file

```
#import "poo1ViewController.h"


@implementation poo1ViewController

@synthesize a;
@synthesize b;
@synthesize c;
@synthesize d;
@synthesize e;
@synthesize fView;
-(IBAction) ia:(id)sender {
}


@end
```

LIke this I have a method for all the button, now I want all the button to be present when the App opens but to access all the user needs to scroll down, I don't know how to implement the scrollview in the present view, so the poo1ViewController.xib view gets to be scrollable.

Comment: 1) What's the issue? What are you able and what aren't you able to do?
2) Post a piece of code to help us undertand better your problem.

Comment: @vfn I have updated my post, please look into it

Comment: @Andrew's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. I created buttons programmatically and couldn't access all of them because the view didn't scroll. Important for the scrolling is the last line of my code. First i set a specific starting point "positionX" for the buttons. After that i loop through my database and create a button for each entry. After creating a new button, i increment positionX by the height of a button + 10. When all buttons have been created, the loop ends, and the value of positionX will be also used for the height of my UIScrollView.

```
int positionX = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < [activities count]; i++) {

    //get single object out of nsarray
    Activity *activity = [activities objectAtIndex:i];

    //create button for an activity
    UIButton *activityButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [activityButton setTitle:activity.definition forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    activityButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, positionX, 300, 40);
    [self.activityScrollView addSubview:activityButton];

    positionX += 50;
}

//set the content size of the scroll view
[self.activityScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, positionX + 20)];
```

Maybe [this website](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/45113) is useful too. I solved the problem after reading the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIScrollView` won't be `scrollable` in `Interface Builder`. You'll either have to stretch it out and add your `UIButtons` where you want them to be and then resize the `UIScrollView` at the end, OR you'll need to add your `UIButtons` `programmatically` to your `UIScrollView`.

Personally, I'd opt for doing this one programmatically.  You can either create the `UIButtons` programmatically as well (what I'd opt to do), or if you want to cut `corners`, you can just add them to your `UIScrollView` in your `xib` file and make sure you have an `IBOutlet` connecting them to your code. Then in your code set their frames to where you want them.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)
    a.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, a.frame.size.width, a.frame.size.height);    
    b.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, b.frame.size.width, b.frame.size.height);

    // etc. etc. for the rest of your buttons
```

Then make sure you set the frame and `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView` otherwise it won't scroll.

```
  myScrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
  myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                        myScrollView.frame.size.height
                 + how many pixels you want it to be able to scroll up and down>;
}
```